# Instal WiFi driver in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless

Today I just got into the world of Ubuntu but I cannot install the drivers for my WiFi dongle which is a Netgear A6210.

I noticed similar questions but I don't know how to proceed so I come here asking for help.

I don't really understand the procedure to follow in this "tutorial": https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210

Comment: What is the problem to follow the instructions on github? But I am afraid it won't work for modern Ubuntu releases. It is 3 years old.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are going to have issues with this one as the code appears to be buggy. Your kernel most likely would have the "CONFIG_FORTIFY_SOURCE" option enabled. To verify this, run this command from a terminal:

```
cat /boot/config-`uname -r` | grep CONFIG_FORTIFY_SOURCE
```

Here is the output I got from mine:

```
CONFIG_FORTIFY_SOURCE=y
```

If you get the same output as mine, you won't be able to compile it that driver "as it is" due to buggy code:

```
In function ‘memcpy’,
    inlined from ‘rt_ioctl_iwaplist’ at /home/marko/Desktop/Netgear-A6210/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.c:549:2:
./include/linux/string.h:340:4: error: call to ‘__read_overflow2’ declared with attribute error: detected read beyond size of object passed as 2nd parameter
    __read_overflow2();
```

According to a user called `genodeftest` [here](https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210/issues/81):

> This issue is a result of the new config option **CONFIG_FORTIFY_SOURCE**,
>   which acts like glibc’s **FORTIFY_SOURCE** in trying to detect some bugs
>   with memcpy at compile-time. As a very dirty workaround, you could
>   disable that config option.

and [here](https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210/pull/83):

> Thanks to **CONFIG_FORTIFY_SOURCE**, the compiler refused to compile this
>   buggy code.

To disable that option, it would require you to recompile the kernel and this is not a simple task for novices. I do not advise you to disable that option.

My suggestion is to keep an eye until someone fixes the error.